# Error when web scraping is called through my personal server with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, error-handling, user-agent

I'm brand new to coding and have finished making a simple program to web scrape some stock websites for particular data. The simplified code looks like this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Personal_User_Agent'}

fv = f"https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=JAGX"

r_fv = requests.get(fv, headers=headers)
soup_fv = BeautifulSoup(r_fv.text, 'html.parser')
fv_ticker_title = soup_fv.find('title')
print(fv_ticker_title)
```

The website would not work until I created a user agent, but then it worked fine. I then created a website through python's local host which also worked fine, and so I thought I was ready to make the website public via "python anywhere".

However, when I went to create the public website, the program shuts down every time I go to access information through web scraping (i.e. using the user_agent). I didn't like the idea of using my user agent for a public domain, but I couldn't find out how other people who web scrape go about this problem when a user agent is required for a public domain. Any advice!?

Answer (score 0):

I would add some random headers to rotate through rather than my own headers.  Something like this should work:

```
import random

header_list = [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_18_3) AppleWebKit/537.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/82.0.412.92 Safari/539.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.12; rv:87.0) Gecko/20170102 Firefox/78.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/82.0.12.17 Safari/535.42'
]

fv = f"https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=JAGX"

user_agent = random.choice(header_list)
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

r_fv = requests.get(fv, headers=headers)
soup_fv = BeautifulSoup(r_fv.text, 'html.parser')
fv_ticker_title = soup_fv.find('title')
print(fv_ticker_title)
```

or Option 2.

Use a library called [fake-headers](https://pypi.org/project/fake-headers/) to generate them off the cuff:

```
from fake_headers import Headers

fv = f"https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=JAGX"
    
headers = Headers(os="mac", headers=True).generate() 

r_fv = requests.get(fv, headers=headers)
soup_fv = BeautifulSoup(r_fv.text, 'html.parser')
fv_ticker_title = soup_fv.find('title')
print(fv_ticker_title)
```

Really depends on whether you want to use a library or not...